# Why php socket_read function is returning "$p86i9"45C @"?

Tags: php, sockets, server, apache2

I am having problem with `socket_read()` function in my php project.
I have gps device which is sending me position data to my server hosted on Azure VM with Apache2 web server on it.

Problem is that this function should return string after creating, binding, listening and socket accepting but it return something that I can not read. It returns data like this `$p86i9"45C             @` but it should be like this:

> *HQ,9170383669,V1,185625,V,2234.9299,N,11354.3998,E,000.00,000,011119,FFFFBBFF,220,05,00064,1261#

Here is my code:

```php
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    set_time_limit(0);

    ob_implicit_flush();

    $address = '10.0.0.4';
    $port = 5050;

    echo "Starting ... \n";

    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) or die("Blabla".socket_strerror(socket_last_error())."\n");
    socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) or die("Blabla".socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock))."\n");
    socket_listen($sock, 5) or die("Blabla".socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock))."\n");

    do {

        $msgsock = socket_accept($sock) or die("Blabla".socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock))."\n");
        $buf = socket_read($msgsock, 2048, PHP_BINARY_READ) or die("blabla ".socket_strerror(socket_last_error($msgsock))."\n");
        echo "$buf\n";
    } while (true);

    socket_close($sock);

?>
```